# Fabulous 40 for Sharepoint 2010

Tags: fab-40

Does the "Fabulous 40" exist for 2010. If so where can you get it? Is there an automated way of installing all 40 on a new install of 2010?

Answer (score 6):

[No](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2010/08/18/sharepoint-2010-products-upgrade-and-the-fabulous-40-application-templates.aspx), but you can build one by standing up a 2007 farm, creating a Fab40 site, then upgrading to 2010, then export the .wsp. Admittedly a bit of messing around, and not everything will work. But the good news is a community member has already created the [wsp files](http://techsolutions.net/Blog/tabid/65/EntryId/17/Fab-40-Templates-for-MOSS-2010.aspx) and made them available for download, which should save some time.

And to be honest, some of them weren't that fabulous, so think of them as a starting point for development of new site templates.

Comment: +1 for "And to be honest, some of them weren't that fabulous..." LOL :)))))

Answer (score 2):

No, these will not be available for SharePoint 2010, [quote from original article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2010/08/18/sharepoint-2010-products-upgrade-and-the-fabulous-40-application-templates.aspx):

> Microsoft is not releasing new
>   versions of these templates for
>   SharePoint 2010 Products. Also, .stp 
>   files are deprecated and can't be used
>   to create new sites when you upgrade
>   to SharePoint Server 2010 or
>   SharePoint Foundation 2010.

You could still install and use some of them but I wouldn't recommend that. Check [this article](http://www.sharepointjoel.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=0cd1a63d-183c-4fc2-8320-ba5369008acb&ID=374) for additional guidance and links on Fab40 upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Fabulous 40 are not supported in 2010, and in some environments you'll have issues upgrading them to 2010 (missing templates, templates not 2010 compatible, missing features, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Somebody has worked on an update of these templates for SP 2010 (disclaimer: not tested):

http://techsolutions.net/Blog/tabid/65/EntryId/17/Fab-40-Templates-for-MOSS-2010.aspx

Another series, for Foundation, here:

http://www.techsolutions.net/Blog/tabid/65/EntryId/18/Fab-40-for-Sharepoint-Foundation.aspx